# How do laser levels work?

Tags: laser

How is the laser able to move around corners, or able to draw a vertical line?

Is there one laser diode for each red line, and is the diode then being made to sweep the beam along the wall? Are all the diodes then coordinated thus producing those lines and points? Is the sweep at a particular frequency? How is the diode moved? Mechanical or electronic sweep?

Kind of like what a CRT horizontal/vertical deflection ckt does to the electron gun?

[image: Laser Level]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about EE.

Comment: Line lenses: http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=9394

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually either a lens or a mechanical sweep with a fixed laser and rotating mirror.